# Save data from TextInput in Kivy Python

Tags: python, android, upload, kivy, save

Firstly I'd like to thank every single one of you for being part of this wonderful community.

EDIT: The app allows the user to create and delete TextInputs similar to a "To Do List". I want the app to be able to keep the created widgets (TextInputs) and its contents (Text) after closing and re opening it.

My question is the following. I wish to be able to save/load the TextInput Widgets created and the information in them thus allowing the user to open the app and keeping the info.
You do not need to give me the finished code, with a small hint on where to look or how to approach the matter would be very much appreciated!

Here is a simplified version of the code.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button, ButtonBehavior
from kivy.factory import Factory as F
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
class CButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class DisApp(App):
    number = NumericProperty()
    timer = None
    cont_id = None
    def build(self):
        return kv
    def create_task(self,instance):
        print(instance.text)
        if instance.text == "1":
            self.root.get_screen("second").ids.container_1.add_widget(F.Task())
        elif instance.text == "2":
            self.root.get_screen("second").ids.container_2.add_widget(F.Task())
        elif instance.text == "3":
            self.root.get_screen("second").ids.container_3.add_widget(F.Task())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DisApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<Task@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        size: (2, dp(40))
    Button:
        text: 'remove'
        on_press: root.parent.remove_widget(root)
        size_hint_x: .15
        size_hint_y: None
        size: (.5, dp(40))

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "press me"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Accordion:
            orientation: "vertical"
            AccordionItem:
                title: "ONE"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "1"
                        on_release: app.create_task(self)
                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        GridLayout:
                            size: (root.width, root.height)
                            id: container_1
                            cols: 1
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size_hint_y: dp(40)
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            row_default_height: 40
                            row_force_default: True
            AccordionItem:
                title: "TWO"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "2"
                        on_release: app.create_task(self)
                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        GridLayout:
                            size: (root.width, root.height)
                            id: container_2
                            cols: 1
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size_hint_y: dp(40)
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            row_default_height: 40
                            row_force_default: True
            AccordionItem:
                title: "THREE"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "3"
                        on_release: app.create_task(self)
                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        GridLayout:
                            size: (root.width, root.height)
                            id: container_3
                            cols: 1
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size_hint_y: dp(40)
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            row_default_height: 40
                            row_force_default: True
        Button:
            size_hint: (1,.15)
            text: "back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do. To save data you can write it to storage and to reuse read from storage.

Comment: @ApuCoder Thanks for your reply! I edited the question to make it clearer!!

Comment: You can create a data container (maybe `dict`) to hold the required data and update it whenever adding new widget. Write those data to storage in `on_stop` method and retrieve them and update the gui in `build` or `on_start` method.